# Copy particular text from a web page using VBA

Tags: excel, vba, copy, paste

I want to copy particular text from a web page using vba and paste it into my macro. Can anyone please help me with it?

I have tried below code but I am not able to get text from webpage using vba. Any help is highly appreciated.

```
 Sub get_text_from_web()
    Dim request as Object
    Dim response As String
    Dim html As new HTMLDocument
    Dim website As String
    Dim ab As Variant
    
    website = "http://www.google.com"
    Set request = CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")
    request.Open "GET", website, False
    request.Send
    response = StrConv(request.responseBody, vbUnicode)
    html.body.innerHTML = response
    ab = html.getElementsByClassName("gNO89b")(0).innerText
    MsgBox ab
    
    End Sub
```

Comment: What error do you see and at which line, please?

Comment: Please post proper code, your code can't even compile. If this is the actual code, you did not name your `sub` and `website = http://www.google.com` should be `website = "http://www.google.com"` with the quotes around the URL.

Comment: What to you want retrieving?

Comment: Have you checked on here? There are so many examples of scraping.

Comment: You are not going to get any proper result from google.com using XMLHTTP btw, the html file is just a bunch of scripts.

Comment: Please, replace `getElementByClassName` with `getElementsByClassName` (you missed an "s"), and `website` is wrong from two points for view. It should be a string (between double quotes) and you have to use "https" instead of "http": `website = "https://www.google.com"`. Anyhow, the class you search for does return an empty string for all its elements (two)... I asked you "what you want retrieving", but you did not say anything...

Comment: Thank you all  for your inputs, I have edited the mistakes pointed out. I am getting "Access is denied" error. When I am clicking on Debug it is taking me to Line "request.send".

Comment: What I want to do is go to a webpage through vba and copy a text present there and paste it into my excel.

Comment: Did you change this part `website = "https://www.google.com"`, as I suggested? I mean 'https:` instead of `http:`...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can scrape the element with the class `gNO89b` from google.com with xhr. But this is the search button and it has no `innertext`, but an attribute `Value` with the content `Google Search`.

Furthermore, you obviously cannot read google.com with `MSXML2.XMLHTTP`, but have to use `MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP.6.0`. Since I don't know the exact differences myself, I can't explain why this is the case.

But even that is not enough. In addition, a *UserAgent* must be specified. These are identifiers that a client sends along to identify itself. One can use a browser identifier for xhr:
`.setRequestHeader "User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:91.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/91.0"`

Also the line `StrConv(request.responseBody, vbUnicode)` does not work for you. It is also unnecessary to write the content of the returned document into a variable first. You can copy it directly into the body of the HTML document provided:
`html.body.innerHTML = .responseText`

With the following VBA code, the content of the search button is output. But I am pretty sure that none of this will help you. There is no universal code for reading data from web pages. Since each page is programmed individually, an individual code must be developed for each page. I think the Google search button is not your goal ;-)

```
Sub get_text_from_web()
  Dim html As Object
  Dim website As String
  
  website = "https://www.google.com"
  Set html = CreateObject("htmlFile")
  With CreateObject("MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP.6.0")
    .Open "GET", website, False
    .setRequestHeader "User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:91.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/91.0"
    .Send
    
    If .Status = 200 Then
      html.body.innerHTML = .responseText
      MsgBox html.getElementsByClassName("gNO89b")(0).getAttribute("value")
    Else
      MsgBox "Page not loaded. HTTP status " & .Status
    End If
  End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you @zwenn . Yeah, you guessed it right. Google search button is not exactly something I am looking for. I need to copy and paste a temporary generated password text from a site and need help on that.

Comment: @NupurPriya A solution for your concern basically depends on whether the page in question requires JavaScript or not. E.g. to generate the password or to build the complete required page content or something else without which it does not work. If so, you need a runtime environment for JS. From VBA, that is SeleniumBasic. You can use it to automate Chrome. But that only works if you are allowed to install it. If no JS is needed, it can also work with xhr. So the approach you used in this thread. But we answerers have the problem of not knowing your website to look for the used web technologies